# How do I add two data frames together

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
df = data

shuffle = df.sample(frac=1)
dfrand = np.array_split(shuffle, 3)

s1 = dfrand[0]
s2 = dfrand[1]
s3 = dfrand[2]

trainingSet1 = s1+s2
trainingSet2 = s1 + s3
trainingSet3 = s2 + s3
```

Here I have randomized a dataframe and split it into three equal sets. I am trying to add the sets together but do now know how that would be done. for example I want trainingset1 to be equal to s1 + s2, how is this done?

Comment: use pd.concat. also no images . refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: when I tried pd.concat(s1,s2) I tried that but when I ran it said TypeError: first argument must be an iterable of pandas objects, you passed an object of type "DataFrame"

Comment: what is the expected output

Comment: You need to pass an iterable of DataFrames to concat. Try `pd.concat([s1, s2])`